# Running unix shell command from django app hpsted on aws and using apache2 web server

Tags: python, django, operating-system

I am using os module for running shell command in django code .
It is working fine on local but when running on the apache2 server it is not running

```
 os.system(commandDict[i])
```

on local it is giving status code **0**
but on production server it is giving status code **1**

can any one suggest alternative or what is going wrong in this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check if there is anything in standard output?
You can rather use `subprocess` package to achieve this.
The reason for the command to not run on the server could be the permission level of the user associated.

Comment: @ShahadIshraq thanks for your response the response code  of this is 256. I have also tried **subprocess** module but  it also not working it is giving reponse **(None, Ndne)**. I have also tried to give permission 644 to the all file and folder but it is not working.

Comment: The problem could be with the user that is running the server. What does the specific command you are trying do?

Comment: @ShahadIshraq Thanks for the help it was permission issue. I changed the permission for directory then it is working fine . yeah you are right it is related to user permission .once again thanks :)